# I have ajax call for insertion. data get inserted but it not goes to success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

my ajax code is like below , it not goes to success function

```
function saveRecord() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "admin.aspx/inserData",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'text',

        data: JSON.stringify({
            "name": $("#name").val(),
            "uName": $("#uname").val(),
            "password": $("#pwd").val(),
            "adminType": $("#seAdmin").val(),
            "serviceArea": $("#selServiceArea").val(),
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        Success: FnInsertSuccess,

        Error: FnInsertError,
    });
}
```

and `FnInsertSuccess` is here

```
function FnInsertSucces(result) {
    alert(result.d);
        if (result.d == "Success") {
            console.log("data inserted");
            // $("#tblData tbody").append("<tr style='cursor:pointer'><td>" + $("#name").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#selServiceArea").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#seAdmin").val() + "</dt><td><a class='fa fa-pencil'></a><a class='fa fa-times' onclick='FnDeleteRow(this)'></a></td></tr>");
        }
        else if (result.d == "Fail") {
            alert("Not Successfully Insert");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have set `dataType: 'text'` however it looks like you're expecting JSON by the way you treat the `result` like an object

Comment: Also, the keys `success` and `error` should be all lowercase

Comment: Also, you sure the URL is `admin.aspx/inserData`? Not "insertData"?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use success call like below. It will work.

```
$.ajax({
url:"Where u need to go",
data: //data to send  
success:function(data) {
  alert(data); // data will be having the stuff that gets returned from the servlet.
}
complete: //here call ur fninsert function. This will work after the ajax     call is completed.
```

});

Comment: `FnInsertSuccess` is also function ! There is nothing difference your answered

Comment: @DavidJawphan except lowercase "success" which is very important though I'm not sure if that was the main point in this answer

Comment: thanks Phil the  problem was all about using uppercase

Answer (score 0):

```
function saveRecord() {
$.ajax({
    url: "admin.aspx/inserData",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'text',

    data: JSON.stringify({
        "name": $("#name").val(),
        "uName": $("#uname").val(),
        "password": $("#pwd").val(),
        "adminType": $("#seAdmin").val(),
        "serviceArea": $("#selServiceArea").val(),
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    success: function(result){
        FnInsertSuccess(result)
     },

    error: function(data){
      FnInsertError(data);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Why create wrapper functions for `FnInsertSuccess` and `FnInsertError`?

Comment: now dear how to refresh the datatable in FnInsertSuccess function.i using code like      $('#tblData').fnDestroy();
                $('#tblData').DataTable().ajax.reload(); bu show an error

Answer (score 0):

```
function saveRecord() {
  var name =  $("#name").val(),
  var uName = $("#uname").val(),
  var password =  $("#pwd").val(),
  var adminType =  $("#seAdmin").val(),
  var serviceArea =  $("#selServiceArea").val(),
$.ajax({
    url: "admin.aspx/inserData",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',

    data: {
        name: name,
        uName: uName,
        password: password,
        adminType: adminType,
        serviceArea: serviceArea
    },
    success:function(data){
     FnInsertSucces(data);
    }
});
}
```

-> Try like this

Comment: now dear how to refresh the datatable in FnInsertSuccess function.i using code like      $('#tblData').fnDestroy();
                $('#tblData').DataTable().ajax.reload(); and show error   TypeError: $(...).fnDestroy is not a function i'm using datatable 1.10

Comment: You can write FnInsertSuccess function's code in success function or you can call FnInsertSuccess function in success fumction.

Comment: i have FnInsertSuccess  function which work, but now to redraw datatable in this function